# Adjust div height based on scroll

Tags: jquery, html

I need to increase the height of a div while the user scroll the page.

The site in question is this:
http://cdscostruzioni.digitalcanali.com/

The div that has to change its height is the menu on the right.

I elaborated the following code, but the problem is that the div should reach 100% of the height when the user is at the bottom of the page, now the height grows too fast.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
        var $myDiv = $('.nav__front');   
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        $myDiv.width( st );    
        if( st == 0 ) {              
            $myDiv.hide();
        } else {
            $myDiv.show();
        }
    })
    .scroll();                     

})
```

how can I fix the issue?

Comment: In Chrome I can't see the menu grow at all, in the moment I scroll it gets out of sight. Why don't you simply make the navigation sticky at the top right with media queries for mobile display?

Comment: Hi Sascha, I cleaned the internal cache of the site, now you should see it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the current scroll position in relation to the page height and calculate the scroll percentage from these two numbers. I updated your code, hope that helps:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

        var $myDiv = $('.nav__front');

        // calculate the percentage
        var percentScrolled= scrollPos / scrollHeight * 100;

        $myDiv.width( percentScrolled + '%');    
        if( st == 0 ) {              
            $myDiv.hide();
        } else {
            $myDiv.show();
        }
    })
    .scroll();                     
})
```